# Selenium Locators are not working for this site?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, elements

```
public class LoginPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input') and @name='username']")
    private WebElement userName;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input') and @name='password']")
    private WebElement password;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@class,'oxd-button') and @type='submit']")
    private WebElement loginButton;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void enterUserName(String userNameValue) {
        userName.sendKeys(userNameValue);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String pwd) {
        password.sendKeys(pwd);
    }

    public void clickLoginBtn() {
        loginButton.click();
    }

}


@When("User logins in with correct credentials")
    public void user_logins_in_with_correct_credentials() {
        SeleniumManager.getInstance().getDriverPath("chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        login = new LoginPage(driver);
        login.enterUserName("Admin");
        login.enterPassword("admin123");
        login.clickLoginBtn();

    }
```

[image]

Error Message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input') and @name='username']"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception thrown 'NoSuchElementException' can be due to pageload issue as there is nothing wrong with the webelement 'userName'.
These are common issues faced in test automation services company while creating frameworks.

Try to use dynamic waits like below to avoid flaky failures in executions:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input') and @name='username']"))).click();

or

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input') and @name='username']")));

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

- You have used class names incorrectly
- Why to try xpath? I suggest that should be the last option
- Try with `driver.findElement(By.name("Username")).sendKeys("ABC");` OR  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='Username']")).sendKeys("ABC");`below as per your code

```
    @FindBy(name = "username")
```

OR

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[(@class,'.oxd-input--active') and @name='username']")
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Is this whole string the class name ? oxd-input oxd-input--active or just part of it?

Comment: THis locator still doesnt work :| No such element exception

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input--active') and @name='username']"}

Comment: Not sure ,why its not working...everything looks fine.

Comment: Can you try with placeholder instead of name property

Comment: Sure,  @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input--active') and @placeholder='Username']")
-- This still doesn't work.... very confused.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@class,'oxd-input--active') and @placeholder='Username']"}

Comment: Also, the LoginPage class elements are initialized in constructor by PageFactory.init()

Comment: Could you please try at your end ... at this site?

Comment: Try this : @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Username']")

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@placeholder='Username']"}
-- This failed too....

Comment: These are not changed dynamically... so why is xpath not working?

Comment: Also, both <div> have the same class  - Username and password are in different div tags.

Comment: Its working as expected on my machine friend using : By.name and By.cssSelector. Updated my answer above. All the best!

Comment: @harry234 Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use customize XPATH, I use the following code in python, hope it helps you:

```
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='username']").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above code worked for me but my below code works for me as I was using only selenium to test without python.
You need to add sleep timer for that after the website is open, 40seconds or
60seconds to enter the username and password and click login.

```
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
//timer i kept as 60 you can keep 40
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                
//find username
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username']")).sendKeys("Admin");
                
//find password
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("admin123");
                
//login button click
                
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).submit();
```